# Printing List<PictureBox> - One Image per page

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a *List of PictureBox*. Following code is working for a single PictureBox. How can I **print each PictureBox (or Image) in a new page** regardless of the paper size? Thanks !

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
   doc.PrintPage += Doc_PrintPage;
   PrintDialog dlgSettings = new PrintDialog();

   dlgSettings.Document = doc;

   if (dlgSettings.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
       doc.Print();
   }
}

private void Doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
   float x = e.MarginBounds.Left;
   float y = e.MarginBounds.Top;
   Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(picBox1.Width, picBox1.Height);

   //THIS IS OKAY FOR A SINGLE PICTURE BOX. 
   picBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, 
            new Rectangle(0, 0, picBox1.Width, 
            picBox1.Height));

   e.Graphics.DrawImage((Image)bmp, x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try keeping track of the image index:

```
int bmpIndex = 0;
List<Bitmap> bmps = new List<Bitmap>();

void pd_BeginPrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e) {
  bmpIndex = 0;
}

void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) {
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmps[bmpIndex], new Point(e.MarginBounds.Left, 
                                                 e.MarginBounds.Top));

  ++bmpIndex;
  if (bmpIndex < bmps.Count) {
    e.HasMorePages = true;
  }
}
```